# How to upload contentBytes chunk by chunk on Graph url return by createUploadSession graph API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api

As per microsoft graph API documentation the createUploadSession graph API only return the URL where attachment can upload but how to upload attachment chunk by chunk in javascript? does anyone knows? Thanks in advance.
I'm referring this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reference for attaching the Attachment to a post in JavaScript, Please refer this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/post-post-attachments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#example-1-include-a-file-attachment)

```
    const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

const reply = {
  post: {
    body: {
      contentType: 'text',
      content: 'Which quarter does that file cover? See my attachment.'
    },
    attachments: [{
      '@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment',
      name: 'Another file as attachment',
      contentBytes: 'VGhpcyBpcyBhIGZpbGUgdG8gYmUgYXR0YWNoZWQu'
    } ]
  }
};

await client.api('/groups/1848753d-185d-4c08-a4e4-6ee40521d115/threads/AAQkADJUdfolA==/reply')
    .post(reply);
```

Hope this helpful.